# What do you do with questions where the correct answer has changed after a game update?

Tags: discussion

About a year ago, I asked a [question about Die2Nite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12190/is-there-a-way-to-survive-outside-the-town-walls-overnight-in-die2nite) asking if you could camp outdoors and survive. At the time, the answer was no. However, when Season 2 started (a few months after I originally asked the question), the answer changed to yes.

What should we do in cases like this where game patches or updates change the answer to a question?

Comment: Fairly sure this has come up before and can be flagged/closed as dupe, but for the life of me I can't find the original right now.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it would have, but I couldn't find it either.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz This might be it: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2306/should-questions-about-obsoleted-mechanics-be-simply-removed

Comment: In the case of my question, the mechanics still exist, which makes it a little more of a gray area, as it's still a valid question (although granted, in this case, one a lot less likely anyone won't already know the answer to).

Comment: I think LessPop is referring to this meta question as being a dupe, not your gaming question.

Comment: and fyi you should just unaccept the other answer and accept the new one that's correct.

Comment: Your last comment is exactly the question I really had when posting this, yx. I wanted to know if basically taking away reputation for a once-correct answer was the correct thing to do. You seem certain it is, but it it wasn't so black & white to me (nor is it after reading what Dave McClelland linked, either). I've done your suggestion, though.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-should-we-deal-with-out-of-date-questions-answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you own the question, then yx.'s advice is on the spot - unaccept the now-incorrect-answer and accept the now-correct-answer.

It's not unlike if, say, someone posts just a workaround or weak answer to the question that's *sufficient*, but not optimal. You accept because it works. Two months pass before someone shows up with exactly the answer you need. In this case, the other answer isn't invalidated or anything, but the new answer *is* more useful and is in fact what you've been looking for.

The scenario where the old answer is invalidated should play pretty much identically to the above.